# Hide activity indicator in status bar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, statusbar

I am using pull to refresh table and in pull to refresh table there is already a activity indicator. And when I pull the table then calling a web service then the activity indicator in status bar appears, but I want to hide the indicator in status bar in whole app.  When I am connecting with webservice even then I don't want to show the network indicator. How can I do this?

I am using following code:

```
UIApplication* app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
app.networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
[self connectserver];
```

Before connecting to server I am hiding the indicator but it's not working.

Comment: Go through this answer.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15703122/networkactivityindicator-in-ibaction/15703269#15703269

Answer (score 1):

you can call this method of activity indicator:

```
[app.networkActivityIndicator stopAnimating];
```

and if activity indicator is on superview the you have to remove it from superView:

```
[app.networkActivityIndicator removeFromSuperView];
```

Hope this might help.

Comment: when i click on connect button and webservice is called then network indicator starts showing in status bar.. as by default its visibility is NO. but in my project i dnt know how it is YES by default. is there any setting of this?

Comment: @KsK you have to check attributes/properties of that network activiy indicator in storyboard that whether its visibility is YES or NO,if you are using storyboard .

Comment: i am not using story board

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible=FALSE;
```

and also check whether you make it visible somewhere else or not.

Comment: by programatically i have not set it to yes anywhere. is there any setting for this?